# Old range wiring for a new NEMA-6-50 receptacle with 50AMP breaker

Tags: wiring, range, welder

I have an old range in my garage that I want to use for powder coating.I currently have a NEMA 6-50 receptacle with a 50 AMP breaker-installed 2 years ago for my ARC welder. I have a 6 gauge 3 wire cord with green/white/black wires (shown) with a male end that fits the NEMA 6-50 receptacle (shown). How can I hard wire the cut end of the 3 wire cord (shown) to the range? Possible? Safe of course?
Model (shown). wiring diagram (shown).

[image: cut cable and range connection]
[image: plug end of cable--just like ARC welder]
[image: range model]
[image: range wiring diagram]

Thank You

Comment: OP stop reposting questions.   You somehow have 2 accounts (probably because you changed browsers and hadn't [registered your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts).   Now, please [merge your accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can regain control of your original question.   (and yes, if you ask me, the ability to post from unregistered accounts is a mess, because it causes this.)

Answer (score 0):

Stop reposting this question. It's on here 3 or more times with answers.

You can't to what you want to do. Your welder needs 120V, 120V and a ground so that's 240V & ground. Your cord has black, white & green wire so one hot goes to black, the other hot goes to white (code lets you do that) and ground goes to green.

Your oven needs 120V, 120V, a neutral and a ground. It's not straight 240V like the welder,  It needs 120V also so the neutral is required. The cord you want to use has a black, white and green wire. If the black goes to the black wire, the white to the white (neutral) and the green to ground.... guess what, nothing to the red so oven won't work. Even if you foolishly decided not to ground the oven, you would never be allowed to use the green wire to connect to the red oven wire and change the outlet.  You need a four wire cord, plug and outlet or a grounded FMC with a black, red and white wire.

Comment: OK Jack, now that makes sense. No other answer was given like that in detail. I will have an electrician put in a breaker and female 4 plug receptacle in the basement.

Comment: Now that leads me to two more questions Jack and I can't find the answers in here.                                    Can I hard wire a 4 wire cable  to the oven (what color wire goes where??) and run the cable 25ft to the 4 prong receptacle in the basement?. Or run the appropriate extension cord? Sorry 3 questions. Again we are talking 4 uses per month.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Extension cords are not recommended for permanent installations.

Comment: @Wierd Four wire cable would probably have a black, red, white and green wire and would hatch your oven terminals.  Twenty five feet is way too long in my opinion to run /cable in an open area. It will be carrying close to 50 amps and that much exposure is dangerous. Have your electrician run an extra 20 feet of conduit and pull in wire, probably cheaper than the cable.  As Matt S stated, extension cords are not allowed for permanent use.

Comment: JACK  I have decided to have an electrician put in a 50 amp breaker with a NEMA 6-50 receptacle in my subpanel. In hooking up the 4 wire cable to the range. Is it black to black, red to red, white to white and the green to the ground screw on the chassis? Do I keep the neutral strap to the ground wire connected?

Comment: One more. Can I run a 25 foot 50amp 4 wire extension cord from the range to the basement? Again, this would only be connected when I use the oven for powder coating. Maybe 4 times a month. Then I disconnect every time. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, and you remove the neutral strap.  I've already stated my views on a 50 amp extension cord running 25 feet. Talk it over with your electrician, see what he thinks.

Comment: Thank You Jack I will confer with electrician